# I can't select header's text properly using jQuery CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a code in jQUery which extracts text from all headers(h1 to h6) inside "a" in the document. 
For example:

```
<a>  
  <h1>TEXT I WANT TO CAPTURE1</h1>
</a>
```

As a output, i would expect:

```
TEXT: TEXT I WANT TO CAPTURE1
```

Here is my code:

```
 $(function(){
   var text = [];
   var h12 = [];
   h12 = $("a > :header");
   for(j in h12){
       text[j] = $(h12[j]).text();
      $('body').append("<b>TEXT:</b> "+ text[j]);   
  });
```

The code accomplish this task, the problem is that he isn't able to capture the text from such structure:

```
<div>
        <div>
            <div>  
              <a>
                  <h1>TESTE EXTREMO1</h1>
              </a>  
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem and get the text of the h1 element inside an "a" in this context? Possible the problem is related to wrong CSS selecting, but i can't figure out exactly what did wrong! Thanks.

Comment: If you fix the syntax errors, like using a `for..in` loop, the loop not being closed etc, it should work just fine

Comment: There's *nothing* wrong with your **selector**.  https://jsfiddle.net/d2tLm0w1/   It's one of: 1) your dodgy js code (use .each() not for..in) 2) the html is not as presented here 3) the selector is not as presented here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some syntactical and structural errors here. This whole thing can be shortened to:

```js
$(function() { // on DOM-ready
    $("a > :header").each(function() { // for each header that's a direct child of an anchor
        $('body').append("<b>TEXT:</b> " + $(this).text()); // append its text to the body 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <a>
        <h1>TESTE EXTREMO1</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Be careful with `<a>` elements with no attributes; browsers tend to not treat them like anchors without at least an `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your for loop. Also, to add to an array use `.push`.

```
$(function(){
   var text = [];
   var h12 = [];
   h12.push($("a > :header"));
   for(j in h12){
       text[j] = $(h12[j]).text();
      $('body').append("<b>TEXT:</b> "+ text[j]); 
      }
  });
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0c8p18yr/).

Comment: I'm going to keep this here just to show some syntax errors you made but @Cory's answer is better.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i modified the original code of my project to post here, and forgot to close the brackets. Anyway, thanks for your help ;) And if you are wonder what TESTE EXTREMO means, it's written in portuguease, in english it would be: extreme test haha